# Java formula to compute discount dynamically

Tags: java

I need to implement an operation in my java program.

So I have the item, the price of it is 6,00€, but if the user get three of these items I can get a discount of 3,00€. So

```
int quantity = 3;
double discount = 3.0;
int quantityItem = 3;
double priceItem = 6.0;

double totalPrice = priceItem * quantityItem;
if(quantityItem == quantity){
   totalePrice = totalePrice - discount;
}
```

The previous code is ok. But if I get 5 items the correct totalePrice should be:

priceItem (6€) * quantity (5) = 30€ - 3.0€ (discount) = 27€.

If I get 6 items the correct totalPrice should be:

priceItem (6€) * quantity (6) = 36€ - 6.0€ (discount) = 30€.

How can I write the code to make this dynamically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify the number of "groups of 3" of something bought, you need to divide the number bought by 3. Specifically, you want to use [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which basically means "divide by 3, then ignore the decimal part". So

```
1 / 3 = 0
2 / 3 = 0
3 / 3 = 1
4 / 3 = 1
5 / 3 = 1
6 / 3 = 2
...
```

In Java, division between two integers performs integer division by default, so you can calculate the number of "groups of 3" like so.

```
int discountQuantity = quantity / quantityItem;
```

Then you apply the discount that many times.

```
double totalPrice = priceItem * quantityItem - discountQuantity * discount;
```